# Sorting an object based on time and avoiding explicit NULL checks

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a POJO based on time. I figured out that there are possibilities for NPE so I have placed appropriate NULL checks.

But I want to know if there is any Java primitive method in J2SE or some other library such that I can avoid explicit NULL checks. I know there are many such good method in `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` but none suffice my requirement.

In below code `ABC.getCal()` returns a `Calendar` object.

```
    Collections.sort(abcList, new Comparator<ABC>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ABC o1, ABC o2) {
            if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
                return 0;
            return a1.getCal.compareTo(a2.getCal());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any library will use a null check behind the scenes, and will ultimately make an inference about how to treat null. In your case you need to decide for any null do you want it to sort null values first or last (or discard them altogether), and it is a decision that is firmly in your control.

Comment: I am just trying to delegate this in some way .. Just like `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` helps not to so such things explicitly but use their library .. I think @JustinKSU has given a fair answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) is a great way to compare two objects.  It is null safe and makes the code clean.

For example:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {

    private String cal;

    public String getCal() {
        return cal;
    }

    public void setCal(String cal) {
        this.cal = cal;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass o) {
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(this.cal, o.getCal()).toComparison();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a working example, not the same as what is in the docs ??

Comment: Added example as requested.

Comment: It doesn't completely satisfy what I am looking for because I still have to do `a1.getCal()` which means if `a1` is NULL then there will be NPE. But I guess what you have provided is the closest I can get ..

Comment: Yes.  This only works if you are defining the item as Comparable versus defining your own Comparator implementation.  As far as I know you must implement null checking in a comparator.